# how to disable weak ciphers in Google App Engine Java?

Tags: google-app-engine

We just had a PCI compliance scan and failed due to allowing weak ciphers.
How do we disable TLSv1.0, DES, 3DES ciphers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submit a ticket to Google Cloud Support with a list of projects and request that the protocol and ciphers be disabled for your projects.

Comment: This is great.  I didn't know that Google was able to do this for GAE.  Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: IIRC there's a legal requirement that this be available for FedRAMP customers and I'm confident Google will be able to offer this to any customer that requires it. Cloud Support will be able to confirm.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this works. I opened a support ticket with GCP support and asked to disable the weak ciphers. They submitted the request same day, but it did take almost 3 weeks to propagate. Now passes security scan and nmap reports min strength is A.

Comment: @RobertD, thanks for letting us know that this worked.  Did you need to sign up for paid support to get this done?

Comment: Yes, via paid support.

Comment: This is my personal opinion not Google's (my employer's). Every customer receives support (https://cloud.google.com/support/#support-plans). Paid support is a way for you to influence the quality of support service that you receive. If you're paying Google for cloud services and you have justifiable business reasons to disable older versions of protocols|ciphers, I'd be disappointed to learn that Google turns you away because you're not paying for support. I think you should also try to justify the $100/month minimum to get more responsive support too. Again, this is my personal opinion.